# Render component in Fable-Elmish

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

I have set up a standard SAFE application with the `dotnet new SAFE` command resulting in the two Server and Client projects (and the Shared folder).

The Client project has the *Client.fs* file with the view function and the bootstrapping code, which is just as the template generates it:

```
Program.mkProgram init update view
#if DEBUG
|> Program.withConsoleTrace
|> Program.withHMR
#endif
|> Program.withReact "elmish-app"
#if DEBUG
|> Program.withDebugger
#endif
|> Program.run
```

I have now added a simple component:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
    data : int
}

type MyComponent(initialProps) =
    inherit Component<MyComponentProps, obj>(initialProps)
    do
      base.setInitState({ data = initialProps.data })

    override this.render() =
        h1 [] [str ("Hello World " + this.props.data.ToString())]

    override this.componentDidMount() =
        // Do something useful here... ;)
        console.log("Component Did Mount!")
```

But I cannot figure out how to properly instantiate this component in the `view` function. I really think this ought to work:

```
let view (model : Model) (dispatch : Msg -> unit) =
    MyComponent({data = 42}) :> ReactElement
```

But this results in the browser in the - now - dreaded:

*Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.* I really don't get that since the type is ReactElement which should be fine...

Instantiating the component manually and calling `render()` does sort of work, but of course `componentDidMount()` is not called:

```
let myComponent = MyComponent({data = 42})
myComponent.render()
```

So: *How do I get MyComponent properly instantiated and "injected" into React?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ofType` from `Fable.Helpers.React`

```
open Fable.Helpers.React
let view (model : Model) (dispatch : Msg -> unit) =
    ofType<MyComponent,_,_> { data = 42 } []
```

Comment: Thanks! You could improve the answer by stating that the two _s are the type of the props and state, respectively.